# Python Pandas style highlight specific cells for each column with different condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, highlight, pandas-styles

I'm trying to highlight specific cells for each column with different condition which their value matches the condition for each row.

Below image is what I want to achieve:
[The table I attempt to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptzLQ.png)

I searched google and stackoverflow but none of these can meet my requirement. Can anyone who's familiar with Pandas Style could assist?

Below are the codes I tried and failed:

Ex1

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,3,1], [3,7,2], [2,4,4]], columns=list("ABC"))

def highlight(s):
    return ['background-color: yellow' if (v>2) else 'background-color: white' for v in s]
df.style.apply(highlight, axis=0)
```

Ex2

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,3,1], [3,7,2], [2,4,4]], columns=list("ABC"))

Column_limit = (df['A'] > 6) | (df['B'] > 2) | (df['C'] < 3)
df[Column_limit].style.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: yellow', subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, ['A', 'C']])
```

Ex3

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,3,1], [3,7,2], [2,4,4]], columns=list("ABC"))

subsets = pd.IndexSlice[:, 'A']
df.style.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: yellow', subset = subsets)
```

Comment: There are only 3 columns?

Comment: In my real case, there are many columns. I just posted a simplified example here. Your second answer meets my requirement too. Appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is same number of conditions like some number of columns use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,3,1], [3,7,2], [2,4,4]], columns=list("ABC"))

def highlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'

    # condition
    m = pd.concat([(x['A'] > 6), (x['B'] > 2), (x['C'] < 3)], axis=1)
    #print (m)
    #empty DataFrame of styles
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    #set new columns by condition
    return df1.mask(m, c1)


df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```

If there is a lot of columns and need processing only some of them:

```
def highlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'

    #empty DataFrame of styles
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    #set new columns by condition
    
    df1.loc[(x['A'] > 6), 'A'] = c1
    df1.loc[(x['B'] > 2), 'B'] = c1
    df1.loc[(x['C'] < 3), 'C'] = c1
    
    return df1

df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```

EDIT:

If need specified all masks but in last step filter only some columns use:

```
def highlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'

    #empty DataFrame of styles
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    #set new columns by condition
    
    df1.loc[(x['A'] > 6), 'A'] = c1
    df1.loc[(x['B'] > 2), 'B'] = c1
    df1.loc[(x['C'] < 3), 'C'] = c1
    
    need = ['A','C']
    df1 = df1[need].reindex(x.columns, fill_value='', axis=1)
    return df1
```

Or remove masks which not necessary:

```
def highlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'

    #empty DataFrame of styles
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    #set new columns by condition
    
    df1.loc[(x['A'] > 6), 'A'] = c1
    df1.loc[(x['C'] < 3), 'C'] = c1
    
    return df1

df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much @jezrael for the prompt response. This is exactly what I want! I spent a few days on this question, you did save a lot of my time. May I have a further question. If I exclude the condition (greater than 2) for column B and I only want to display the rows who matches conditions for column A and C (greater than 6 and less than 3 respectively). For example, it will only display two rows with index 0 and 1 in my case, like the image here [link](https://imgur.com/a/g5zjykD). How can I add a filter in my code?

Comment: @KelvinLo - So it means removed `df1.loc[(x['B'] > 2), 'B'] = c1` ?

Comment: Yes, remove the condition for Column B, but not to display the third row (index 2). Only show the rows with highlighted number. Just like this image [link](https://imgur.com/a/g5zjykD)

Comment: @KelvinLo - Not underatand, need remove styles for column B? In picture are grey color, it is necessary?

Comment: My apology for the grey picture, re-uploaded new one. [link](https://imgur.com/q2IQytQ). If I don't apply the condition to Column B and I want to only display the row who matches the condition for Column A and C.